# Up to what extent can we prove results in linear algebra (and subjects that depend on it) without any use of basis for a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Well, I'm mostly just curious after seeing some proofs involving tensor products that depend on choosing a basis for a vector space that got me wondering whether they could or could not be proven without doing so.

It may be the case that choosing a basis for a vector space makes a proof much easier, but could there be a case where a proof without doing so is impossible? And if so, could the lack of such a proof cripple an entire part of a theory?

Comment: A vector space that has an uncountable basis would be one where in some cases you can’t even specify a basis other that just use the fact that it has one. This is because the proof that the basis even exists is not constructive.